# Linearize product of $x\cdot y \text{ with } x,y \in \{-1,0,1\}$ for MILP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, quadratic-programming, logical-constraints

I have a problem where I have many products between variables drawn out of $\{-1,0,1\}$. Could you suggest a linearization in terms of variables in  $\{-1,0,1\}$ or $B_1 - B_2$ where $B_i \in \{0,1\}$ possibly with a constraint like $1\geq B_1 + B_2$ or $1 \leq B_1 + B_2$ to get rid of double encoding of $0$ when found helpful.

I tried to find a way to construct this using the linearization of the product of Booleans but I found no way to do so elegantly (that is do so without implementing the CNF of the Karnaugh diagram for $B_1$, $B_2$ of the result). The fact that such a CNF encoding is possible suggests that there might exist a more appropriate formulation for MILP.

Comment: What about $$
x \cdot y = (x_1 - x_2) \cdot (y_1 - y_2) = x_1y_1 - x_1y_2 - x_2y_1 + x_2y_2,
$$ where $x_1,x_2,y_1, y_2$ are binary? Here, you can easily linearize the products of binary variables.

Comment: Can you submit that as an answer? I see 3 new variables being introduced when the double representationof 0 is being resolved which is good. I would wait a bit longer and see if there is a more succint answer in terms of {-1,0,1}.

Comment: @worldsmithhelper, would you say, why not try to define integer variables whose bounds are limited to the $\{-1,...,1\}$ and linearizing with e.g. MacCormick method? Have you had any force to use boolean multiplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write $x=B_1-B_2$, $y=B_3-B_4$, and $z=B_5-B_6$ and supply the nine solutions for which $z=x\cdot y$, $B_1+B_2 \le 1$, $B_3+B_4 \le 1$, and $B_5+B_6 \le 1$, PORTA returns $B_i \ge 0$ and the following seven inequalities:
\begin{align}
- B_1        - B_3               + B_6 &\le 0 \\
- B_1               - B_4 + B_5        &\le 0 \\
       - B_2 - B_3        + B_5        &\le 0 \\
       - B_2        - B_4        + B_6 &\le 0 \\
- B_1 - B_2               + B_5 + B_6 &\le 0 \\
              - B_3 - B_4 + B_5 + B_6 &\le 0 \\
B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4 - B_5 - B_6 &\le 1
\end{align}
The resulting system has only the nine originating solutions.

Comment: For reference http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/PORTA/ and http://porta.zib.de/